# Retrieving data from database for comparison

Tags: laravel

I am able to retrieve items and its details from the database but what i want to do is, when i get an item, i compare its quantity to a certain number.

**Controller**

```
 $item = Item::all();

 if($item->quantity = 5)
{
  return $response;

}

else 

{
   //
}
```

What is happening here is, it actually sets 5 to the item's quantity but instead i want to get the quantity of the item selected and compare if it is equal to 5. How do i do this?

Comment: Use == (equals to) instead of = (assignment operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value with a single `'='` since it's an assignment operator.

Instead, compare the values with `'=='`

```
 $item = Item::all();

     if($item->quantity == 5)
    {
      return $response;

    }

    else 

    {
       //
    }
```